# Bss section --> invalid combination of operands

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

i have got a Problem programming **nasm** under **Linux**.

my problem is

```
/home/maximilian/Schreibtisch/Programmierung/meinCompiler/var2.asm:6:  warning: character constant too long
    /home/maximilian/Schreibtisch/Programmierung/meinCompiler/var2.asm:6: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /home/maximilian/Schreibtisch/Programmierung/meinCompiler/var2.o: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

my nasm Code:

```
section .data

section .text
global _start:
_start:
mov HALLO, "HALLO"
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80

section .bss
HALLO: resb 4
```

could anyone Please help me?

I have searched about this topic, but haven't found anything comprehensive for a NASM-newb

I hope, you can respond me,

tfphd

Comment: HALLO is not a register

Comment: but i have declared it in the bss sectioan haven't i?

Comment: or maybe i have to use push?

Comment: Seems that you have read the fundamentals of either assembly or nasm. If you are looking to have the location `HALLO` contain the value `"HALLO"` then just do that in the declaration (which will have to appear in the `.data` section)

Comment: but then, is it still changeable?

Comment: i mean the variable?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is in the .data section

Comment: You should probably extend the question to include exactly what it is you are hoping to do.

Comment: and in the data section i change it with mov [var], val. don't I?

Comment: I want to have a var, wich gets different values in the runtime

Comment: Note that "HALLO" is *five* bytes long

Comment: ok. you mean i should do sth like

Comment: section .bss HALLO: resb 5

Comment: when i ue the data section, which is the bss section for?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and take the time to read about memory access, the nasm documentation will be very helpful to start with for some fundamental  direction: http://www.nasm.us

Comment: can you please send me a good site?

Comment: `.data` is for initialized (single time, by loading the executable into memory by OS) read+write data. `.bss` is for uninitialized memory, so the OS upon loading executable will only reserve appropriate chunk of memory and make it read+write accessible to the code. Trying to write into some other part of memory (either outside of defined sections, or into section which is read-only) is usually detected by linux, program is terminated, and core is dumped. So .bss is good for reserving some fixed buffers, when you don't need to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: You ask for us to recommend a good site... but your question reveals such a fundamental lack of understanding that pretty much any reference at all that you can find with Google will be an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would declare the memory content in `.data`:

```
section .data
HALLO: db 'HALLO'
```

you would create:

- from point of compilation: a symbol named `HALLO`, which contains address pointing to the `'H'` character
- from point of linux executable: 5 bytes long array containing bytes `72,65,76,76,79`, in read-**write** initialized (once by loading executable) memory area.

So now you can do things like:

```
mov   eax,HALLO                    ; loads value of symbol HALLO into register eax
  ; value of symbol HALLO is address of that array
mov   DWORD [eax+2],0x454D504C     ; writes number over 'LLO?' in that array
  ; creating string 'HALPME' in memory at address HALLO
  ; BUG: notice how 1 character is overwritten after the original array
  ; this may overwrite and destroy some other important value in .data
```

If you would create this in `.rodata` section, it wouldn't be wise to try to modify it. See [NASM sections manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2) for details.

If you create it in `.bss`, the array should be uninitialized, like you did originally, loading the executable into memory will just reserve that space, but not initialize it.

You can't do `mov HALLO, "HALLO"`, that's not how x86 assembly works.
The closest thing to it is `mov DWORD [HALLO],'HALL'` `mov BYTE [HALLO+4],'O'`. You can't store 5 bytes with single instruction in 32b mode.

So if you want to set some memory array to some initial value string, either use `.data` section, and after the initial text bytes add line `times 64 db 0` to enlarge it by 64 bytes (so you can overwrite it with longer string later). - if you want it initialized once per executable run.

Or put that 'HALLO' into .rodata, with some mechanism marking the length of string (either having it as number 5 somewhere, or add 6th byte after O with `0` or some other terminator (`$` is used in DOS for int 21h). And create long enough buffer in .bss like `stringBuffer: resb 69`. And then every time you want to set it to `'HALLO'`, you have to copy 5 bytes from address `HALLO` to address `stringBuffer`.

BTW, notice how naming value 'HALLO' with symbol HALLO is super awkward in such example, as now you have to pay extra attention to recognize where I'm talking about label (symbol/address), and where I'm using it as literal value (bytes).

Overall, if you are just starting with ASM, move from strings to numbers (and don't try to output them, just run in debugger and watch the register/memory values trough debugger).

After you get familiar with byte/word/dword, addresses, and basic arithmetic instructions, then check how strings are encoded in memory (ASCII/UTF-8/UTF-16), and how it looks from the position of number machine (CPU). Or follow any nasm tutorial, it will very likely start with some "hello world" display, which will probably not explain into depth, why that magic `db 'hello world',10` works as string with int 80h (eax,4;...).

---

Finally, the info on `x86` tag is quite large, containing many further resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: I am a little confused, but i think I'll find out.

Comment: Well, as always read it few times, try to figure it out, try to figure out what is confusing you at most, ask about that ... and repeat whole process.

Comment: can you please breakdown this line : mov   DWORD [eax+2],0x454D504C

Comment: `mov`: Intel *"move"* instruction to *copy* Value from one place to another. **From place** in this case is the immediate value in instruction opcode, **Value** itself is `0x454D504C` (32bit number, which consists by intentional accident of four ASCII codes. Read it in memory as ASCII text: will look as 'LPME'). **to place**: The `[` and `]` around toValue will cause CPU to use that toValue as address, to write the **Value** into memory at address toValue. `DWORD` tells assembler to write 32bits Value (4 bytes of it). `eax+2` is address HALLO+2 (address pointing to first 'L' in 'HALLO' array).

Comment: which means, [] is just a pointer. Doesn't it? and 0x45D504C is a hex of the Ansi-Chars? Am i rigth?

Comment: When you do `mov [eax],1` (error), assembler can only gues, if that `1` is meant to write into memory 8b, 16b or 32b. So using `BYTE/WORD/DWORD` is mandatory in NASM with immediate values. (64b = QWORD, etc). So you must do `mov word [eax],1 ; 16bit one`. When you do `mov [eax],bx`, NASM can deduct you want to write 16 bits from the `bx` value size, no need to write `mov WORD [eax],bx` (although it may help you catch mistakes, when you use wrong size of value on one side).

Comment: but when i say eax, doesn't it automatically see, i mean 64 and not ax or ah?

Comment: That would be `mov eax,1` = 1 is 32bit value, because eax is 32bit. So that `1` will end in the CPU register eax. But `mov [eax],1` means something completely different, that value `1` (of unknown size) should land into memory, at address specified by `eax` value. Addressing in 32b mode is done by 32b, that's obvious. But how many bytes will land at that address, that has to specify the value. If value to write is `bx` (`mov [eax],bx`), it's obvious 16bits are written. But if value is `1`, it can be any supported bit width. So you have to specify it.

Comment: I will probably extend the "Assembly" documentation here by further theoretical text stuff, even if several people think the docs should be short code examples, but these questions of newcomers, not understanding what is register and memory, would be then easy to reroute there. :/ These are difficult to explain [thoroughly] in few characters in comment/answer.

Comment: `eax` is register, containing 32 bit number. `<size_modifier> [eax]` is place in memory addressed by value in register eax (of size defined by size_modifier). So in `[eax]` the number in eax is used as pointer. Without `[]` the number is used as number. So the `[]` changes the way, how value in eax is interpreted by CPU. "pointer" is a bit limiting the usage of such number, while the CPU doesn't really care, you can use any number in any way, as long as you use some valid instruction opcode. (including ways causing access of protected memory, crashing your code)

Comment: Exception in Intel syntax (from `[]` usage) is `LEA` (Load Effective Address). This instruction may look like `lea eax,[esi+edx*4+14]` ... vs ... `mov eax,[esi+edx*4+14]`. The difference is that `lea` is first half of that `mov`, the CPU will take esi, edx, 14, and will calculate the address, from where the value would be loaded by `mov`. But it does **not** contact memory, it just loads `eax` with that final address (in `lea` instruction). In `mov` it would continue with the address, contacting memory, waiting for value from it, storing the value into `eax` (dismissing calculated address).

Comment: could you please send me a link to a doc? i haven't found one yet.

Comment: your searching skills are worrying me a bit... (added some links at end of answer ... the last one contains probably everything you need to master x86 assembly ... in a couple of years...)

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/249 - so far the easiest way how to learn C++ in 21 days. Essentially it's the same for asm, just asm is a bit easier to learn, and lot more harder to use effectively where it makes sense.

Comment: What is variable? Let's say you have C++ like `unsigned short positionX;` ... nasm: `positionX:    dw   0`  in .data. To load copy of value into register bx: `mov bx,[positionX]`. To load copy into ebx: `movzx ebx,WORD [positionX]` To store new value into it: `mov WORD [positionX],34515`. To copy value from ebx into it - do NOT, ebx is 32b, positionX is `dw` = 16b WORD only. `mov [positionX],bx` is closest thing, truncating ebx to correct size. ... that's with integer numbers.

Comment: Strings are array of bytes. C++ `char name[100];` = `name: resb 100  ; max size 100 chars` .. `strcpy(name, "player");` = naively: `mov byte [name],'p' mov byte [name+1],'l' mov byte [name+2],'a' mov byte [name+3],'y' mov byte [name+4],'e' mov byte [name+5],'r'` .. advanced: `mov dword [name],'play'  mov word [name+4],'er'` .. or create the `strcpy` function, and copy 'player' defined in .rodata as `stringPlayer: db 'player'` into `name` array in .bss/.data.

Comment: ie. firstly you must decide, what is the variable, how it looks in memory. What is the meaning of it's bytes, and how many of them you need. For example on Intel x86 the 32 bit numbers are stored from least significant byte, so a number `0x12345678`, when stored in memory natively as dword, and viewed byte by byte, it will look like: `78 56 34 12` (each pair of hex digits is single byte). (nasm quirk: mov dword[],'abcd' stores as `61 62 63 64`, not `d c b a`. That's special behaviour of `'chars'`). Then to init it, you simply fill up those bytes with values as you want them. Any way you wish.

Comment: after properly learning Assembler i finally understood. Thnk you :)